# How to modify a task in Windows Task Scheduler without having permission?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-update, windows-task-scheduler

My computer wakes up every day at 1:00 by (`powercfg -lastwake`)

```
'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\UpdateAssistantWakeupRun'
```

when I want to modify the task it does not react for OK. When I try to disable it I am getting:

```
The user account you are operating under does not have permission to enable this task.
```

I have an administrative account but I am not able to modify a task. Is there a way how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) from Sysinternals PsTools.
Run Windows Task Scheduler with the command ([No permission to disable a task in Task Scheduler](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/no-permission-to-disable-a-task-in-task-scheduler/4ec2c460-7c2f-4593-b84f-c9b1687ae797))

```
psexec.exe -i -s %windir%\system32\mmc.exe /s taskschd.msc
```

and in running GUI is possible to modify tasks any desirable way.